# Core Data custom migration without migration policy?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, core-data, core-data-migration

I am changing the model of my Core Data app in a big way for the next update, and custom migration is definitely needed. After reading Apple's docs on migration policy, I find it very confusing and wondered if there is an easier way. I am thinking, why not just bring up the data in the old context/model, and bring up a blank context with the new model, and copy object one by one into the new context/model and perform any needed logic in between? This way, I can even make use of logic in my NSManagedObject subclasses to construct data in the new model instead of working with the mechanism in migration policy. Has anyone tried something like this with any success?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing myself.

Comment: I think setting up two stacks and doing a deep copy between them is easier, that's what I plan to do. I chatted with @drewmccormack on Twitter about this, and he says the same thing.